# Can I create relations between two existing ruby on rails models with existing data?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, relationship, join

I have two models with existing data in a live app which currently don't have any relations to each other. They were mainly used for storage and quick look up, but now we see a need to join them:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: subscriptions
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  app_id            :string(255)
#  user_id           :string(255)
#  effective_date    :datetime
#  expiration_date   :datetime
#  last_validated    :datetime
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  active            :boolean
#  subscription_type :string(255)
#

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: apns_tokens
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  app_id     :string(255)
#  user_id    :string(255)
#  apns_token :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class ApnsTokens < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I need to find all the apns_token's from the apns_tokens model that belong to the same user_id. I would like to be able to query something like:

```
subscription = Subscription.where("app_id = ? AND user_id = ?", params[:app_id], params[:user_id]).last
token = subscription.apns_token.apns_token
```

The user_id in both subscriptions and apns_tokens model is unique.

1) Is it possible to create a has_one belongs_to relation and how would one populate the new foreign key 'subscription_id' in the apns_tokens model?

2) What is the quick fix here, how can I write a sql statement in rails to join on user_id?

EDIT: Quick fix that works but there must be a better way in one query?

```
subscribed_users = Subscription.where("active = ? and app_id = ?", true, app.app_id).collect { |u| u.user_id }
apns_tokens = ApnsTokens.where(user_id: subscribed_users).collect { |t| t.apns_token }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `subscription.user.apns_token` or `apns_token.user.subscription` should work no need to nest those models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question, you have two models that share a value (user_id in this case) and you want to create a relationship between them.

Maybe you could play with the primary_key and foreign_key params in the `has_one` relationship, that allow you to use other columns than `id` and `relationship_id`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Following the API docs you could write

```
class Subscription

  has_one :apns_token, primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :user_id

end

class ApnsToken

  has_one :subscription, primary_key: :user_id, foreign_key: :user_id

end
```

Another solution that comes to my mind is using an intermediate relationship.

Since you have `user_id` columns I guess you have a `belongs_to` relationship in Subscription and ApnsToken classes.

If you have `has one` relationships in the User class you may use the `through` param in the `has_one` relationship to say that you have a subscription/apns_token through the user relationship.

```
class User

  has_one :apns_token
  has_one :subscription

end

class Subscription

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :apns_token, through: :user

end

class ApnsToken

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :subscription, through: :user

end
```

I haven't tested this code for this example but both solutions may work :)